# Styling google maps my location button in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

So I am trying to use a floating action button instead of the default google map's my location button. Any ideas of how can I do that?
I've tried many ways, I tried to call the `MyLocationButtonClick()` event inside my `FloatingActionButton` with either the `map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled` true or false but it did not zoom the user position.
Any help is welcome!
Thanks for your time!

This is my xml with the map and the button I want to replace for the google maps my location button.

```xml
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_myLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#fff"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_my_location_24"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my kotlin `onCreate()` with my floating button click listener

```kotlin
val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courier_map, container, false)

// starts google places client
Places.initialize(this.requireContext(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key))
placesClient = Places.createClient(requireContext())

// starts fused location
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())

view.btn_myLocation.setOnClickListener {
    map!!.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener  {
         false
    }
}

val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
return view
```

Comment: Don't wrap event listener inside another event listener. `map.setOnClickListener` should be outside `btn_myLocation.setOnClickListener`

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni Hi, thanks for your comment. I did it now but it still did not solve my problem. Do you have any idea how can I call that event listener from my `FloatingActionButton` listener?

Comment: You need to add some logic inside `FloatingActionButton` `clickListener` to zoom to user position. `setOnMapClickListener` is another event listener which won't do anything on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the map's camera as follows,

```
map.moveCamera(
   CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
```

to zoom into user position.
Read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views) for more details